# Is Hibernate batching generating the correct statements?

Tags: hibernate

I'm using hibernate and trying to understand if my batching configuration works as expected.

What I expected in the log was to have the following kind of statements for inserts:

```
insert into Table(field1,field2)
values (?,?), (?,?) ... REPEATED BATCH SIZE TIMES  ... (?,?)
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
insert into Table(field1,field2)
values (?,?)
insert into Table(field1,field2)
values (?,?)
... N INSERTS, WHERE N = BATCH SIZE
Executing batch size: BATCH_SIZE
```

So the batching seems enabled and working but the query generated seems different from the expected.

Is this the right behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it's the right behavior.

Batching doesn't consist in generating a giant query. It consists in adding the same insert statement [into a batch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch--) several times, with different parameters, and then to [execute the batch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--). This allows still using the same prepared statement, and still allows doing a single round-trip to the database.